# Make JSON based on available fields

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create a filter string according to the fields available with the following code, how could i improve the following with a switch case or better way?

```
   if ((this.selectedCity === 'City') && this.selectedCategory === 'Category' && this.fromDate === '') {
            this.filter = `{}`;
        } else if ((this.selectedCity !== 'City') && this.selectedCategory === 'Category' && this.fromDate === '') {
            this.filter = `{"location.city":"${this.selectedCity}"}`;
        } else if ((this.selectedCity === 'City') && this.selectedCategory !== 'Category' && this.fromDate === '') {
            this.filter = `{"category":"${this.selectedCategory}"}`;
        } else if ((this.selectedCity === 'City') && this.selectedCategory !== 'Category' && this.fromDate !== '') {
            this.filter = `{"date.start":{"$gte":"${this.fromDate}"},"date.end":{"$lt":"${this.toDate}"}}`;
        } else if ((this.selectedCity !== 'City') && this.selectedCategory !== 'Category' && this.fromDate === '') {
            this.filter = `{"location.city":"${this.selectedCity}","category":"${this.selectedCategory}"}`;
        } else if ((this.selectedCity !== 'City') && this.selectedCategory === 'Category' && this.fromDate !== '') {
            this.filter = `{"location.city":"${this.selectedCity}","date.start":{"$gte":"${this.fromDate}"},"date.end":{"$lt":"${this.toDate}"}}`;
        } else if ((this.selectedCity === 'City') && this.selectedCategory === 'Category' && this.fromDate !== '') {
            this.filter = `{"date.start":{"$gte":"${this.fromDate}"},"date.end":{"$lt":"${this.toDate}"}}`;
        } else if ((this.selectedCity !== 'City') && this.selectedCategory !== 'Category' && this.fromDate !== '') {
            this.filter = `{"location.city":"${this.selectedCity}","category":"${this.selectedCategory}","date.start":{"$gte":"${this.fromDate}"},"date.end":{"$lt":"${this.toDate}"}}`;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend building the filter in steps, starting with an empty object `{}`. You then add attributes according to the selected city, category and date. And finally, you convert it to a JSON string via `JSON.stringify(filter)`:

```
let filter = {};

if (this.selectedCity !== 'City') {
  filter.location = {
    city: this.selectedCity
  };
}

if (this.selectedCategory !== 'Category') {
  filter.category = this.selectedCategory;
}

if (this.fromDate !== '') {
  filter.date = {
    start: {'$gte': this.fromDate},
    end:   {'$lt':  this.toDate}
  };
}

this.filter = JSON.stringify(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify` ignores `undefined` values:

```
JSON.stringify( { a: 1, b: undefined } )  // '{"a":1}'
```

so it can be shortened to:

```
this.filter = JSON.stringify( {
  city    : this.selectedCity     == 'City'     ? void 0 : this.selectedCity,
  category: this.selectedCategory == 'Category' ? void 0 : this.selectedCategory,
  date    : this.fromDate         == ''         ? void 0 :
    { start: { '$gte': this.fromDate }, end: { '$lt': this.toDate }
} );
```